# React-Native Android emoji

Tags: android, react-native, emoji

I am developing a React-Native app where users will be able to send images with captions and also create comments. I would really like to support emoji for this.

At the moment it just works on iOS. The system keyboard automatically provides access to emoji and the render correctly on text views as well. On Android the system keyboard does not provide access to emoji by default and the emoji created by iOS users do not render (just crossed-out square boxes).

I see there is an emoji compat library for Android at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html but I am not sure how well that will work with React-Native. It looks like you have to use non standard text and inputs to get it working and this will be a bit more complicated on RN.I was also testing on Android 7 which should support emoji natively so maybe there is something else wrong here?

Should I get the emoji to render, I am yet to find a way of making them available in the Android keyboard.

Is there a recommended way to get this working in React-Native? Otherwise, is there any standard Android process I can try to port considering iOS seems to just work already?

Answer (score 1):

I have made a request on [React-native](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/adding-emojicompat-to-react-native) and [Expo](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/adding-emojicompat-to-expo) canny if you like this to be added to react native vote it up. Sorry, I didn't have enough reps to make this post as a comment that's why I have added it as an answer.

One solution is to include emoji images in your assets, but I don't recommend it, since it is going to add up to the size of your bundled app.